# How to create BuildConfig values in build.gralde file that can accessible from class files

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I need to add some variables in `build.gradle` file. I did following in app level build.gradle file.

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        buildConfigField "String", "TEAM_NAME", "\"My Team Name\""
```

It synced fine, but i am unable to get the variable in class file.

[image]

I am using following gradle library.

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.0'
```

Comment: have you tried restarting android studio ?

Comment: Try to build the project